# Oddity with legend arguments in R

Tags: r, plot, border, legend

Does someone have a good explanation for the following phenomenon?
Consider the this:

```
col = rainbow(12, alpha = 1)
plot(1)
legend("bottom", border = "white",col = col, legend = 1:12, horiz= TRUE, pch =15, fill = "white")
legend("top", border = "white",col = col, legend = 1:12, horiz= TRUE, pch =15)
```

why are the 
`legend("bottom" ...)` and
`legend("top" ...)` different in width?

Actually I was only trying to remove the legend border....

Comment: btw: `bty = "n"` is what you need to remove the legend box border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxes printed by `fill="white"` are making each item in the legend a bit wider, so that not as many of them fit in the allotted space.

So that you can see those boxes, and make out what's happening, change `fill="white"` to `fill="black"`:

```
col = rainbow(12, alpha = 1)
plot(1)
legend("top", border="white", col=col, legend=1:12, horiz=TRUE, pch=15)
legend("bottom", border="white", col=col, legend=1:12, horiz=TRUE, pch=15, 
       fill="black")
```

[image]

Comment: right. thank you for that. but why is it done this way ? ;-)
and if I may ask. how did you add the plot? (I couldn't find out)

Comment: @TobyElTejedor `fill` makes a box, whereas `pch=15` and `col` together plot colored plotting characters of type 15. They clearly aren't intended to be used together: I'd suggest doing either `legend("top", fill=col, border=FALSE, legend=1:12, horiz=TRUE)` **OR** `legend("top", col=col, legend=1:12, horiz=TRUE, pch=15)`. As for including a plot, there is a little snapshot icon above the window you type text into, or you can do `Ctrl-G`. (There's a slight chance that you may need just a bit more reputation than you have to do it -- maybe around 100, though I can't remember.)

Comment: thanx. fyi: 69 reputation seems sufficient.